# Mongoose compound indexes not being created (Too long)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mlab

I'm having some issues creating multiple compound indexes on one of my schemas in MongoDB. When using MongoLab, I know some indexes are not created when they are too long, due to a naming issue. So I suspect this might be the reason why some are not created

```
var Schema = new mongoose.Schema({ ... });

// Created
Schema.index({
    one: 1,
    three: 1
});

// Not Created
Schema.index({
    one: 1,
    two: 1,
    three: 1,
    four: 1,
    five: 1,
    six: 1,
    seven: 1,
    eight: 1,
    nine: 1,
    ten: 1
});
```

Comment: does it print some thing to the screen when create 2nd index ?
how do you know that the second index is not created ?Did you check in mongo shell ?

Comment: @somallg I didn't add any logging yet. I did check the mongo shell and it wasn't created, hence how I know. When I manually try to create that index, i get the following: "The default index name generated by MongoDB is too long. Please specify a custom name."

Comment: Your right, there is a limitation to the default index name (https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/limits/#Index-Name-Length)
You can specify custom name by passing addition option to Schema.index
`Schema.index({
    one: 1,
    two: 1,
    three: 1,
    four: 1,
    five: 1,
    six: 1,
    seven: 1,
    eight: 1,
    nine: 1,
    ten: 1
}, { name: 'my_index_name' } );`

Comment: Thanks, that was exactly what I was looking for

Comment: @somallg Can you add that as an answer, then I can mark it as solved

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is a limitation to the default index name (https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/limits/#Index-Name-Length)

You can specify custom index name by passing addition option object to `Schema.index`

```
Schema.index({
    one: 1,
    two: 1,
    three: 1,
    four: 1,
    five: 1,
    six: 1,
    seven: 1,
    eight: 1,
    nine: 1,
    ten: 1 }, 
    { name: 'my_index_name' }
);
```

Comment: [“By default, **`<index name>` is the concatenation of the field names and index type.** You can explicitly specify the `<index name>` to the `createIndex()` method to ensure that the fully qualified index name does not exceed the limit.” “**Fully qualified index names,** which includes the namespace and the dot separators (i.e. `<database name>.<collection name>.$<index name>`), **cannot be longer than 128 characters.**”](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/limits/#Index-Name-Length)